# Java8 :: flatMap in optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, flatmap

```
I am new to Java8. In recent project I am trying Optional with map and flatmap to prevent NPE.
```

I tried map and flatmap both with Optional but when I am using flatMap the compiler is giving error.

```
public class Project {
    private ApplicationType applciationType;
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class ApplicationType {

    public String getDirectory() {      
        return "Inside my directory";
    }
}


public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationType appType = new ApplicationType();
        Project project = new Project(appType);

         //When using map its running fine.
        Optional.ofNullable(project)
        .map(prjct-> prjct.getApplciationType())
        .map(appType1 -> appType1.getDirectory())
        .ifPresent(e -> System.out.println(e));

        //When using flatMap.. comiplation error.
        Optional.ofNullable(project)
        .map(prjct-> prjct.getApplciationType())
        .flatMap(appType1 -> appType1.getDirectory())
        .ifPresent(e -> System.out.println(e));

    }

}
```

Sorry if I am missing something basic here.
Just trying to learn and implement java8 features in future projects.

compilation error I am getting -> 
[Cannot infer type argument(s) for  flatMap(Function>)]

Comment: why are you trying to use `flatMap`? just use `.map(Project::getApplicationType).filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment Adrian. Kindly let me know in which scenario I have to  use flatMap when working with Optionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the signature of `flatMap`:

```
public<U> Optional<U> flatMap(Function<? super T, Optional<U>> mapper)
```

The `Function` is supposed to return an `Optional`, so in order to use it, you'll need to write:

```
Optional.ofNullable(project)
    .map(prjct-> prjct.getApplciationType())
    .flatMap(appType1 -> Optional.ofNullable(appType1.getDirectory()))
    .ifPresent(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

Of course, using `map` makes more sense in this example (as in your first snippet, which passes compilation).

Answer (score 2):

Purpose of `Optional.flatMap()` is to unwrap `Optional` from function.

For example, if your `getDirectory` returns `Optional<String>`, then `.map()` call would give you `Optional<Optional<String>>`, but if you use `flatMap()` - it gives you just `Optional<String>`.